# Is there a (clear) target of GHG emissions per year for companies (by industry)?

Tags: greenhouse-gas-emissions

From an individual point of view, we have a clear target to go under **2000 kgCO2eq/year** by 2050. (I need to find an actual source for that target, any suggestions?)

If you want to setup such a target for a company, I guess you cannot have one single number as companies are not equivalent between them because of (1) their size and (2) their "type". However, is it possible to find a target per size and per type?